# ColdFusion 10 REST API UTF-8 Characters

Tags: rest, utf-8, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using ColdFusion 10's new REST API and I'm having trouble with UTF-8 characters.  It seems that ColdFusion 10's new REST API completely mangles non-ASCII characters.  Is there a way around this?

For example, let's say I have an endpoint like this:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/widgets" produces="application/json">

    <cffunction name="echo" access="remote" httpmethod="PUT" returntype="string">       
        <cfreturn GetHttpRequestData().content />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

This endpoint simply responds with exactly what was sent in the request.

Here is my request:

```
PUT http://www.mycompany.com/rest/v1.0/widgets HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: www.mycompany.com
Content-Length: 15

こんにちは
```

Here is the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2013 23:59:09 GMT
Content-Length: 37

ã�“ã‚“ã�«ã�¡ã�¯
```

Note how the response is completely different from the request.

To be 100% certain that this is a problem with the request being mangled by ColdFusion and not a problem with the response being generated by ColdFusion, I enhanced the endpoint to also log the request body into a database, and sure enough, it was already mangled.

Any way around this?

Comment: FYI, I submitted a bug report here, but I'm still looking for a workaround: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3618494

Comment: Shouldn't you be specifying the charset of the request?

Comment: Have you tried checking webserver, I see you are using IIS? And as Peter said, setting utf-8 as default charset where needed. First you could do it in CF admin , "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8", encoding request, encoding response...

Comment: Thank you @zarko.susnjar. Can you advise how I can set the default encoding in ColdFusion Administrator?  I looked everywhere and I couldn't find this setting through the Administrator UI.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't guarantee that adding a `Content-Type` header and specifying a charset of `UTF-8` would fix your problem; but what I *can* tell you is that [Taffy](http://atuttle.github.io/Taffy/) *assumes* UTF-8 and it [doesn't have this problem](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s240/sh/a15822d7-866d-46eb-a703-532da3805cb9/e71c3bc814082032fd497f4f76bc48e8/deep/0/Screenshot%208/27/13%208:55%20AM.png):

[Thumbnail: Click for full size http://note.io/1dLswMN](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s240/sh/a15822d7-866d-46eb-a703-532da3805cb9/e71c3bc814082032fd497f4f76bc48e8/deep/0/Screenshot%208/27/13%208:55%20AM.png)

Here's an excerpt of Taffy's code that gets the request body:

```
<cffunction name="getRequestBody" access="private" output="false" hint="Gets request body data, which CF doesn't do automatically for some verbs">
    <cfset var body = getHTTPRequestData().content />
    <cfif isBinary(body)>
        <cfset body = charsetEncode(body, "UTF-8") />
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn body />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.  This workaround works.  I changed the accepted answer to yours.  Quick question: why do you check if getHTTPRequestData().content is binary?  Isn't it always binary?

Comment: I now know why you check whether the content is binary.  If Content-Type header of application/json is not passed in the request, then the content is not binary.  Bizarre.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I'm pretty sure that when CF sees "application/" in the content type (whether it's JSON, XML, whatever) it comes in binary encoded. Compare application/json to text/json.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your CFC with this code:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfhttp method="put" url="http://localhost:8500/rest/restservices/widgets" result="httpResponse" charset="UTF-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="こんにちは">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

And got the same output as you. Modifying it to include a Content-Type header fixed it:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfhttp method="put" url="http://localhost:8500/rest/restservices/widgets" result="httpResponse" charset="UTF-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="text/plain; charset=UTF-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="こんにちは">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#httpResponse#">
```

So I guess this confirms what AdamT (and Peter) suggested: you need to specify the `Content-Type`.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Setting the Content-Type allowed ColdFusion to handle Unicode characters correctly. But is there a way to set UTF-8 as the default encoding somewhere?  Maybe in ColdFusion Administrator?  I'd like to avoid asking every client using our public API to send this header, because even if I do, some 3rd party developers will forget it and it'll just add support issues.

Comment: There's no harm in UTF-8 encoding every request that comes in, manually (as Taffy does).

Comment: @AdamTuttle, you're right, but I don't control the requests made by 3rd parties.  I can ask them all to include that header, but it would be preferable if I didn't have to.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work with JSON (Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8)?  ColdFusion mangles the unicode characters when content type is 'application/json'.  Any way around this?

Comment: In fact, it seems to work with any other Content-Type, as long as it's not application/json.  For example, this works: Content-Type: text/foo; charset=UTF-8.  But 'application/json' doesn't.  Very bizarre.

Comment: Nothing about ColdFusion mishandling JSON is "bizarre". It's more like "a lifestyle choice". I'll mess around tomorrow and see if I can work anything out (not that I think I can work anything out better than anyone else can, but more eyes on the task might help).

Comment: The code I included in my answer is your work-around. Just force UTF-8 for all requests. It won't hurt anything that doesn't require high-ascii characters, and high-ascii characters will work.

Comment: Adam is correct.  Using CharsetEncode, like DeserializeJSON(CharsetEncode(GetHttpRequestData().content, "UTF-8")), will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do this, too, combining it with ColdFusion's ability to produce custom rest responses.  This example shows how you can force the response into UTF-8.

```
<cffunction name="echo" access="remote" httpmethod="PUT" returntype="void">       
    <cfset response = structNew() >
    <cfset response.status = "200">
    <cfset response.statusText = "OK">
    <cfset response.headers["charset"] = "UTF-8">
    <cfset response.content = GetHttpRequestData().content>
    <cfset restsetResponse(response)>
</cffunction>
```

This is the only happy workaround I've found for non-ASCII character sets thus far.  Using the implicit REST stuff works great until you need UTF-8.  I've found that even setting the request charset is hit or miss, especially if you're taking UTF-8 content out of a database.  This override is partially documented here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-5719eac51353e6bb244-7fec.html

Comment: I can't get this to work.  Setting 'charset' to 'UTF-8' doesn't seem to do anything for me.  I still get '?' in place of extended UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are still having trouble returning UTF-8 characters in the response, it looks like changing your endpoint to return string instead of struct solves the problem.

Example (returning struct):

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" produces="application/json" restpath="foo" returntype="struct">

    <cfreturn {
        hello = "こんにちは"
    } />

</cffunction>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 17:58:25 GMT
Content-Length: 17

{"HELLO":"?????"}
```

Notice that when returning struct, ColdFusion's internal serializer mangles UTF-8 characters.

On the other hand, here's an example where the method returns string and I do the JSON serialization myself:

```
<cffunction name="foo" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" produces="application/json" restpath="foo" returntype="string">

    <cfreturn SerializeJSON({
        hello = "こんにちは"
    }) />

</cffunction>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 17:59:12 GMT
Content-Length: 27

{"HELLO":"こんにちは"}
```

It's bizarre, but seems to work.